# Hiding the internal views and auto adjust the height of the cell swift

Tags: ios, swift

According to the following screenshot I have a table view cell with couple of stack views inside the cell. I want to hide the red circled stack view when it's inside label values are empty. To achieve this specific thing what I have done is just hiding the related stack view as the following screenshot. The related stack view is hiding. That's fine. But I want it to be hidden that empty area and adjust the height of the cell accordingly. I am not using the following function as well.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
         return 150
    }
```

I have used the following function as well. But it's still the same.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        SalaryDetailTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        SalaryDetailTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65.0
    }
```

Could anyone please help me to sort out the issue ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u70u2.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkgzS.jpg

Comment: Instead of hiding the stackView hide the items inside of the stackView

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I did that. But even that space is not removing. Can you please let me know any suitable method for this ?

Comment: You don't need so many stackViews. Just use a single stackView for salary, hours, material, total expenses, and total. If you hide the material label the stackView will collapse the spacing between hours and total expenses. Make sense?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I am bit new in swift. Thanks mate. It make sense.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree By using one single stack view all the other labels inside in it are placing on top of the other. I used vertical stack views. Can you please advice me if you don't mind ?

Comment: Didn't you want the labels on top of each other?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I want the exact view which is shown in the following screenshot. Sometimes the material value and the total expenses values are not coming. In that case I want to hide that space according to the requirement. Do you have any suggestion for that ?

Answer (score 0):

From your first screenshot I can see that you are using AutoLayout. Wrap all your stack views in a base stack view, pin it to the cell and check and fix your other constraints if needed. After that, you need to specify

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

If your constraints are right, AutoLayout will take care of collapsing or expanding the cell when you hide your inner stack view.